Issues with NeoMutt + Home Manager for Gmail Setup
I'm trying to set up NeoMutt declaratively with Nix Home Manager to manage my Gmail account and encountered some challenges. Here’s a summary:
What Works:

Sending emails and retrieving email headers from NeoMutt.
Browsing through all Inbox email headers.

Issues:

Email headers load fine, but I can't view the body. Pressing  on a header shows "No mailing lists found."
Only the Inbox appears in the sidebar; folders like Sent, Trash, and Drafts are missing.
Trouble configuring my University email (non-Gmail-based). Syncing with mbsync produces the error:

Socket error: secure connect to <mail_server> (<mail_ip>:993): error:0A00018A:SSL routines::dh key too small

Configuration Details:
Below is a snippet of my neomutt.nix:
# neomutt.nix (simplified)
accounts.email = {
  maildirBasePath = "Maildir";
  accounts.gmail = {
    userName = gmailname;
    mbsync = { enable = true; create = "maildir"; };
    folders = { inbox = "Inbox"; sent = "\[Gmail\]/Sent\ Mail"; trash = "\[Gmail\]/Trash"; };
    neomutt = { enable = true; mailboxName = "Inbox"; };
    passwordCommand = pass_cmd;
    flavor = "gmail.com";
  };
};
programs = {
  neomutt = { enable = true; vimKeys = true; sidebar.enable = true; };
  mbsync.enable = true;
  msmtp.enable = true;
};
home.packages = with pkgs; [ openssl ];

Generated ~/.config/neomutt/gmail:
set ssl_force_tls = yes
set folder='/home/user/Maildir/gmail'
set spoolfile='+Inbox'
set sidebar_visible = yes
set record='+[Gmail]/Sent\ Mail'
set trash='+[Gmail]/Trash'

Troubleshooting Attempts:

Manual IMAP/SMTP setup instead of flavor. (Failed to load headers.)
Adjusting folders and extraMailboxes options.
Testing different configurations for mbsync.create.
Toggling imapnotify and notmuch.

Any pointers or suggestions are appreciated! Especially if anyone has experience integrating Gmail or non-Gmail accounts with NeoMutt and Home Manager.
